# CollectionView NSInvalidArgument when setting image in cell's ImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uiimageview

I'm working on a collection view to prompt images and I run into an issue. When I try to set an image to my UIImageView (in my cell) It crashes saying NSInvalidArgument here is the log:

```
-[UICollectionViewCell img]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff063f81170
2018-07-10 10:10:50.645635+0200 App[41377:5706851]
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[UICollectionViewCell img]: 
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff063f81170'
```

Here is the part of the code the error:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

   // Configure the cell
   cell.img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test"];
   return cell;
}
```

I'm a 100% sure that it is supposed to work because I used the same method for a UITableView and the images were displayed properly.

Thanks for your reply.

UPDATE: 
 here is a screen of my storyboard if it can help:
  [image: interface builder]

Comment: check your img is set in .xib of your cell CollectionViewCell

Comment: Yes my img property is properly set in my interface builder. (edited the post)

Comment: check your reuseidentifier, make sure it matches.

Comment: set image file in storyboard and see it is loaded without setting up in code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error you posted:

> -[UICollectionViewCell img]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff063f81170

The reason is obvious that the cell instance dequeued from tableview doesn't have the method "img".

I guess maybe the reuseIdentifier is incorrect so that you got wrong class cell instance which does not implement "img" method.

Comment: You were right. I just figure out I'm quite dumb because I just forgot to change this line with my custom cell class.. thanks for your answer.
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]; need to be : 
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[CollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

Answer (score 1):

check your reuse identifier and cast your cell to your class

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 CollectionViewCell *cell = (*CollectionViewCell)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

 // Configure the cell
 cell.img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test"];
 return cell;
}
```